# Assertion failed

Tags: c, opencv, assertion, integral

why do i keep receiving this error when i use `cvIntegral()`

```
if ((image = cvLoadImage(filename,1))==0){ 
return -1;//if there is something wrong exit with -1
   }

image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width++,image->height++),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

cvIntegral(image, image2, NULL,NULL);
cvReleaseImage(&image);//release image and exit
cvReleaseImage(&image2);//release image and exit

return 0;
```

this is the error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (sum.data == sum0.data && sqsum.data ==
>   sqsum0.data && tilted.data == tilted0.data) in cvIntegral, file
>   /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/sumpixels.cpp, line 306
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what(): 
>   /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/sumpixels.cpp:306:
>   error: (-215) sum.data == sum0.data && sqsum.data == sqsum0.data &&
>   tilted.data == tilted0.data in function cvIntegral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cvIntegral`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvintegral#void%20cvIntegral%28const%20CvArr%2a%20image,%20CvArr%2a%20sum,%20CvArr%2a%20sqsum,%20CvArr%2a%20tilted_sum%29) expects the output image to be of type `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`. Also, the number of channels for the source and destination images should be same. You should be doing this:

```
image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width+1,image->height+1),IPL_DEPTH_32F,image->nChannels);
```

Comment: thanks, but i have tried that but keep getting same error OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (sum.data == sum0.data && sqsum.data == sqsum0.data && tilted.data == tilted0.data) in cvIntegral, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/sumpixels.cpp, line 306
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/sumpixels.cpp:306: error: (-215) sum.data == sum0.data && sqsum.data == sqsum0.data && tilted.data == tilted0.data in function cvIntegral

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing `image->width++`. You should do `image->width+1` and `image->height+1`. Also, the number of channels should be same for `image` and `image2`. You will get the exception if the number of channels are different. Check the updated code in my answer.

Comment: i tried it again with image->height+1 and image->width+1 same error :<

Comment: I tried the code. The actual reason is the number of channels. Keep them same. I also get the same exception if number of channels are different.